# Transforming the json data using scala to look like a normalized output

Tags: json, scala, json4s, play-json

I have an input json which is read from a denormalized table. In my scala application, I need to normalize it before returning the resultset.
If below is the sample input:

```
inputJson = {
    "k1": "v0",
    "k2": [{
        "k21": [
            "v1",
            "v2",
            "v3"
        ]}, {
        "k22": [
            "v2",
            "v3",
            "v4"
        ]
    }]
}
```

my output json should look as follows:

```
outputJson =  {
    "k1": "v0",
    "k2": [{
        "k21": [1, 2, 3]
    }, {
        "k22": [2, 3, 4]
    }],
    "values": [{
        "1": "v1"
    }, {
        "2": "v2"
    }, {
        "3": "v3"
    }, {
        "4": "v4"
    }]
}
```

How can I achieve this in scala elegantly with/without using any json manipulation libraries

Comment: Your wanted output is not valid json. `"k2" : ["k21":[1,2,3], "k22":[2,3,4]]` is invalid. Also... `{1:"v1"}` should be changed to `{"1": "v1"}`. To know more about json specification, look at this - http://www.json.org/ . The white sidebar on the right side is json grammer.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh, thanks updated the json syntax as per spec

Comment: Are the keys of your objects (`k1`, `k2`, `k21`) fixed or they can change?